# Model profit/loss of a time series of financial position state changes

Tags: typescript, finance

I'm newly exploring time series databases, and trying to wrap my head around what data I'll store and how I'll query it.  Also, I'm relatively new to TypeScript.  This prototype exercises my current understanding of how it will work.

What I most want feedback on is:

- TypeScript idioms: am I following them? Does anything I'm doing stick out like a sore thumb?
- Am I properly representing this in a way analogous to a time-series database? (TimescaleDB is the one I'm eyeing, if it matters.)

```
namespace Position {
    export enum State {
        BuyingToOpen,
        SellingToOpen,
        Open,
        BuyingToClose,
        SellingToClose,
        Closed,
    };

    export namespace State {
        export type Transition = OrderPlacementTransition | OrderFillTransition;

        export interface OrderPlacementTransition extends TransitionBase {
            newState: Opening | Closing;
            orderId: string;
        }

        export type Opening = State.BuyingToOpen | State.SellingToOpen;
        export type Closing = State.BuyingToClose | State.SellingToClose;

        export interface OrderFillTransition extends TransitionBase {
            newState: State.Open | State.Closed;
        }

        interface TransitionBase {
            timestamp: number;
            positionId: string;
            newState: State;
            affectedAsset: string;
            affectedAssetDelta: number;
        }
    }
}

const positionHistory: Position.State.Transition[] = [
    {
        // placed an order to spend $500 on 2,500 ZRX
        timestamp: 0,
        positionId: '0',
        newState: Position.State.BuyingToOpen,
        orderId: 'A',
        affectedAsset: 'USD',
        affectedAssetDelta: -500,
    },
    {
        // order to spend $500 has been filled, we now hold 2,500 more ZRX
        timestamp: 1,
        positionId: '0',
        newState: Position.State.Open,
        affectedAsset: 'ZRX',
        affectedAssetDelta: +2500,
    },
    {
        // placed an order to sell that 2,500 ZRX
        timestamp: 2,
        positionId: '0',
        newState: Position.State.SellingToClose,
        orderId: 'B',
        affectedAsset: 'ZRX',
        affectedAssetDelta: -2500,
    },
    {
        // order to sell 2,500 ZRX for $505 has been filled
        timestamp: 3,
        positionId: '0',
        newState: Position.State.Closed,
        affectedAsset: 'USD',
        affectedAssetDelta: +505,
    },
];

type ProfitOrLoss = { [asset: string]: number };

console.log(
    positionHistory.reduce<ProfitOrLoss>(
        (profitOrLoss, historyElement) => {
            profitOrLoss[historyElement.affectedAsset] = (
                (profitOrLoss[historyElement.affectedAsset] || 0)
                + historyElement.affectedAssetDelta
            );
            return profitOrLoss;
        },
        {},
    ),
);
```

Result:

```
{
    "USD": 5,
    "ZRX": 0
}
```

Comment: Using `||` is ok for your purpose, but is something I'd try to avoid `(profitOrLoss[historyElement.affectedAsset] || 0)` - you might wanna use the null coalescing operator `??` as it returns the given default value when the left side is `null` or `undefined` only. Besides, the TypeScript stuff looks fine to me